# Winforms: Determine if tree view background clicked

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I am making a `winforms` app where the user can add nodes to a tree view by right clicking on a node or the background. If the user clicks a node, the new node should become the child of that node, otherwise it will be added to the root of the tree view.

My problem is that there is no function to check if the background is clicked. Below is what I have so far. Unfortunately, if a node is clicked right now then the child will be added to both the root and the parent node.

```
private void treeView_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right) addChild(null);
}

private void treeView_NodeMouseClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right) addChild(e.Node);
}

private void addChild(TreeNode parent)
{
    TreeNode node = new TreeNode("new node");

    // If didn't click on a node, add to root, otherwise add to parent
    if (parent == null) treeView.Nodes.Add(node);
    else parent.Nodes.Add(node)

    node.Parent.Expand();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

move your code from `MouseClick` to `MouseUp` (when user releases mouse button). Then check by mouse coordinates is there node on that location. 
Take a look at this code:

```
private void treeView1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var clickedNode = treeView1.GetNodeAt(e.X, e.Y);
    if (clickedNode == null)
    {
        //clicked on background
        addChild(null);
    }
    else
    {
        //clicked on node
        addChild(clickedNode);
    }
}
```